# Clear / Reset Direction Panel in Google Map API v3

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

Every time we search the route by the direction service, the result will be append to the bottom of the direction panel. Some people recommend to reset the panel in div tab as null... Can anyone suggest how to do it...

```
function calcRoute() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'map': map,
    'preserveViewport': false,
    'draggable': true
  });
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(
    document.getElementById("directions_panel")
  );

  // ... code to make Directions API request and display response ...
}
```

HTML part:

```
     <div id="directions_panel" style="width:90%"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't do that it the [example in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-panel)

Comment: Thanks for your responses...
in case i could not initialize the map everytime... as there are many other functions included...
and thus i declare a new directionDisplay inside the calcRoute() function... 
Some people advice to set 'directions_panel = null' in the beginning of calcRoute() function but it is not worked....

Comment: What i want is simply clear the panel and make it available for appending new direction result...

Comment: Can you provide an example (or preferably code) that doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("directions_panel").innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
  document.getElementById("directions_panel").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: This does work, but shouldn't be necessary if the `DirectionsRenderer` is re-used. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

To clear the Directions Panel:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);
```

Initiate the directions panel with:

```
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions_panel'));
```

...where "directions_panel" is your DIV where you want the directions to load.

Same goes for markers:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

From the [Google Maps Javascript API Developer Guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that you define a new `DirectionsRenderer` service each time you call `calcRoute`.

Look at this code from the [demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-panel):

```
  function initMap() {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

    var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
    control.style.display = 'block';
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    directionsService.route({
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

In the `initMap` function, the `directionsDisplay` and `directionsService` services are created. Then, they are *passed to* the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function:

```
var onChangeHandler = function() {
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
};
```

The `calculateAndDisplayRoute` then uses this existing instance of each service, rather than recreating the `directionsDisplay` service.

In your code, you have the following line in your `calcRoute` function:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  ...
});
```

Then there are subsequent calls to `setPanel` and so on. Because you create a new instance of the `DirectionsRenderer` each time you call `calcRoute`, the previous instance(s) are not updated. You need to use the same instance each time, in order to have the route on the map redrawn (as opposed to overlaid over the route created by the previous instance) and the previous directions removed from the panel (as opposed to having the new ones simply appended after those inserted by the previous instance).